# gnome-shell 3.28.2 in ubuntu 18.0.4.01 LTS takes up 100% CPU

Tags: gnome-shell, cpu-load

gnome-shell 3.28.2 in ubuntu 18.0.4.01 LTS takes up 100% CPU causing poor performance and consistent lag

I am running ubuntu under virtual box 5.2.22 with 1 cpu (i7) 4GB RAM, 128MB VRAM, 40GB HDD (solid state)

Comment: Did you install any GNOME extensions?

Comment: GNOME Shell is dramatically slow on VirtualBox even with guest additions installed and enabled 3D acceleration. Consider to switch to other desktop - Xfce, Cinnamon or MATE.

Comment: No GNOME extensions installed.

Comment: I read this is a known bug and 18.10 does not have this.